# Can we add an Item into Drop Down List after the compilation

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have dropdownlist inside a Gridview, which contains names of Medicines. I want that when Doctor opens that page, he could be able to add a medicine that is not present in the list, Is this possible..??

Comment: Your drop down list is probably coming from a table in database. You can provide an interface to modify that lookup table and it will be available inside the grid view

Comment: Yes , It possible, how do you want to do it that matters , Client Side  or Server side , you can add in client side using JavaScript or postback to the server , insert into database , reload it and show it.

Comment: Saurabh, I want it at clint side, but not able to figure out how. How, a dropdownlist will be edited which is already having some data.

Answer (score 0):

See if this can help you.

http://www.devcurry.com/2011/05/jquery-editable-combo-box.html

You would need to make a jquery call to server to add the medicine to the database when new medicine is added to the list. Here is a link to jquery ajax that can be helpful here.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom JavaScript based control like [jQuery AutoComplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). There are many other similar controls as well in many libraries (jqWidgets, extJS etc.).

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to do it in dropdown, make it this way.

`Add a list item named "New" with the value '-1'`
`on dropdown selected event , check if the selected value is -1`
`if yes, bring up a popup with a text box or whatever with a submit & cancel button`

you can do it then..

**For adding list item**

```
ddlcountry.Items.Clear();
ddlcountry.Items.Add("--Please Select country--");
ddlcountry.DataTextField = "Country";
ddlcountry.DataValueField = "CountryId";
ddlcountry.DataBind();

if (ddlrecipient.SelectedItem.Text == "New")
    {
        //Some code here
    }
```

Hope this helps